# Between and is working fine in MySql but not in T-SQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql

We had a project with backend MySQL which we recently migrated to SQL Server 2005.
A query like the one given below used to work fine when MySQL was used where as it is giving unexpected result.

`select * from employees where joindate between '2013-05-01' and '2013-05-01'`

here the starting and ending dates are same.

MySQL used to give the records of employees who joined on **'2013-05-01'**.
Where as T-SQL is giving the records of employees who joined on **'2013-04-30'**

joindate column in the table has time part as well in which we are recording the exact time when the employee joined along with date.

Is there any work around for this problem. Please kindy let me know.

thanks,
dpchimmili.

Comment: May be datetime format problem. You can send datetime to mssql like 'May 01 2013'.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL used to give the records of employees who joined on '2013-05-01'. Where as T-SQL is giving the records of employees who joined on '2013-04-30'`

that is how the different servers implemented the between function differently: for as mySQL includes all dates between and with the same date, T-sql only includes the dates `between` those dates and not the dates itself.

use Where statements as work around `WHERE joindate >='2013-05-01' and joindate <= '2013-05-01'` or jsut `WHERE joindate ='2013-05-01'`

Comment: Then Microsoft would violate the SQL standard. Because the standard *requires* the `BETWEEN` operator to *include* the limits. But SQL Server does evaluate it correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/319b9/1

Comment: I don't think this'll work either since `joindate` seems to be a `DATETIME`, and `2013-05-01` only compares equal to `2013-05-01 00:00:00`, not any time during that day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BETWEEN` with TSQL if you just cast the value to a `DATE`.

```
select * from employees 
where CONVERT(DATE, joindate) 
between '2013-05-01' and '2013-05-01'
```

Better though is to check if the date is less than the next date, since that avoids a calculation per row and will hit indexes better;

```
select * from employees 
where joindate>='2013-05-01' 
  and joindate<DATEADD(day,1,'2013-05-01')
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abe24/1).

Comment: The OP has specified that they are using SQL Server 2005, which doesn't have the `date` type. Therefore, the first suggestion wouldn't work for them. In the second one, it should probably be `joindate>='2013-05-01'` instead of `joindate>'2013-05-01'`. Other than that, I agree.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for the heads up on the typo'd `>`.